# full native application still need root access?

Tags: java, android, networking, corba

Hi I am have to somehow port the emerald compiler to the Android phones. however do I still need to have root access to distribute objects to different phones?  emerald is implemented in C so that is why  I want to go full native. is there a reason why corba is not compatible with android ?

Comment: What is "the emerald compiler"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Corba apart from it's name, but native apps are still subject to the android permission model.

So you have to request the `INTERNET` permission to be able to do network stuff. This doesn't gurantee that corba works at all though, but root access won't help you in that case.